# Make ESLisnt rule to not use async/promise in function

Tags: javascript, eslint

How can I make an ESLinst rule that warns when someone is using async/promise inside a function.

Ex.:

```
class NoPromise {
    privateThings = 'private'
}

class GoodNoPromise extends NoPromise {
    myMethod() {
        return 'all good'
    }
}

function promiseMe() {
    return somePromise;
}

class WrongNoPromise extends NoPromise {
    myMethod() {
        promiseMe.then((result) => console.log('promise fulfilled', result));
        return 'not good'
    }
}
```

I want to make a ESLint rule that will show a warning/error whenever a subclass of `NoPromise` uses a async/promise inside the function.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why would you need such a  feature as no promise in a class?

Comment: Function must be pure and synchronous, anything done in an async won't have an effect. I just want a lint reminder so people don't forget.